# Intellij scalastyle check in multiple projects with

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalastyle

I am working in several scala projects with IntelliJ and the same scalastyle_config.xml in the root of the projects.

Is it possible to have only one config (e.g. in VCS) and IntelliJ uses it from this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, you can vote for the corresponding feature request:

- [SCL-8719](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8719) Possibility to use global scalastyle_config.xml